# codeigniter and ion_auth autocomplete with jquery not working ~ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am making web app by using codeigniter and ion auth. Without ion auth integration into my codeigniter web app my autocomplete field is working properly but when I integrate ion auth library in my codeigniter then autocomplete feature stops working and showing error in console.

```
GET link?term=l 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){ 
          $(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".task",function(e){ 
              $(this).autocomplete({ 
                  source : '<?php echo base_url();?>digital/search_field/task_search', 
              }); 
          }); 
      });
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function task_search(){
    if (!isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        exit;
    }
    $qs = strtolower($this->input->get('term'));     
    $this->pojo->search_task($qs);
}
```

Here is my model

```
public function search_task($qs){
    /*comparing data with the text box*/  
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT t_name FROM task_name WHERE t_name LIKE ('$qs%') ORDER BY t_name LIMIT 5");
    /* It checks the row in database table*/
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['t_name']));
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); 
    }       
}
```

When I searched on google some article says it is csrf issue. I don't know more about CSRF. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem.
The problem is in my Model.
here is my updated Model

```
public function search_task($qs){
  /*comparing data with the text box*/  
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT t_name FROM task_name WHERE t_name LIKE ('$qs%') ORDER BY t_name LIMIT 5");
  /* It checks the row in database table*/
    if($query->result_id->num_rows > 0)
        {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
              {
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['t_name']));
              }
             echo json_encode($row_set); 
        }       
  }
```